# Writing to csv file

Tags: python, csv, file-io, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'R150': 'PN000123', 'R331': 'PN000873', 'C774': 'PN000064', 'L7896': 'PN000447', 'R0640': 'PN000878', 'R454': 'PN000333'}.
```

I need to fill in this sample csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c95mlitjrvyppef/sheet.csv

**example rows**

```
HEADER,ID,ReferenceID,Value,Location X-Coordinate,Location Y-Coordinate,ROOM,ALT_SYMBOLS,Voltage,Thermal_Rating,Tolerance,PartNumber,MPN,Description,Part_Type,PCB Footprint,SPLIT_INST,SWAP_INFO,GROUP,Comments,Wattage,Tol,Population Notes,Gender,ICA_MFR_NAME,ICA_PARTNUM,Order#,CLASS,INSTALLED,TN,RATING,OriginalSymbolOrigin,Rated_Current,Manufacturer 2,Status,Need To Mirror/Rotate Pin Display Properties,TOLERANCE,LEVEL
,,R150,1,,,,,<null>,<null>,<null>,,,to be linked,Resistor,TODO,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,1/16W,?,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>
,,R4737,1,,,,,<null>,<null>,<null>,,,to be linked,Resistor,TODO,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,1/16W,?,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>
,,R4738,1,,,,,<null>,<null>,<null>,,,to be linked,Resistor,TODO,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,1/16W,?,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>
```

Specifically, I need to fill in the PartNumber column based on the keys of the dict I created. So I need to iterate through column ReferenceID and compare that value to my keys in dict. If there is a match I need to fill in the corresponding PartNumber cell with that value (in the dict)....

I'm sorry if this is all confusing I am new to python and am having trouble with the csv module.

Comment: Instead of linking to a file download, please provide a minimal example of the current format of your csv and what your expected output is.

Comment: I can't even access the file you linked!

Comment: Basic overview would be to read in the file into a CSV object (specifically a csv.DictReader), iterate through the rows using next(), check if the ReferenceID is in your given `dict`, and if so add the part number, then output this new array using the DictWriter.  Write up some sample code implementing something like this, and we can help you work out the details.

Comment: IMHO the best way to read a `csv.DictReader` is to use something like `for rowfields in csvdictreader:` as I find using `.next()` unnatural and somewhat awkward. Doing it this way, it's usually very easy to update the fields in the `rowfields` dictionary and write it out using a `csv.DictWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started - here's something that uses the `csv.DictReader` object, and loops through your file, one row at a time, and where something exists in `your_dict` based on the row's `ReferenceID` sets the `PartNumber` to that value, otherwise to an empty string.

If you use this in conjuction with the docs at http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping and http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html - you should be able to write out the data and better understand what's happening.

```
import csv

your_dict = {'R150': 'PN000123', 'R331': 'PN000873', 'C774': 'PN000064', 'L7896': 'PN000447', 'R0640': 'PN000878', 'R454': 'PN000333'}
with open('your_csv_file.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in csvin:
        row['PartNumber'] = your_dict.get(row['ReferenceID'], '')
        print row
```